# console setting in notepad++

Tags: console, notepad++

When I compile my java program in notepad++, it first displays few lines before displaying the results. Is there any setting to suppress (first 7 lines and last 2 lines) lines? I only want to display my results.

```
NPP_EXEC: "java-run"
SET: JAVADIR = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"
$(JAVADIR) = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"
CD: C:\Users\****\Documents\JAVA\Hello
Current directory: C:\Users\******\Documents\JAVA\Hello
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" TestArray 
Process started >>>
1.9 
2.9 
3.4 
3.5 
Total is 11.7
Max is 3.5
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Comment: I can suppress some lines by selecting "No Internal Messages" in NppExec, but it still displays lines containing current directory and READY line. I want to suppress these two as well.

Comment: Anyone has any comment or possible solution.